# Magento 2: Path to place footer.phtml in custom theme

Tags: magento2, php, template, theme, html

**My Theme Path:**

```
app/design/frontend/Mycompany/mytheme/
```

**My Problem:**

Following this [tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html)
I thought that I could use the below path to override the `footer.phtml` template:

```
app/design/frontend/Mycompany/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

I copied and pasted the footer.phtml from [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml) and added `<h3>Test Test</h3>`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
        <h3>Test Test</h3>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml() ?>
        <p class="bugs"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Help Us Keep Magento Healthy') ?> - <a
            href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking"
            target="_blank"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Report All Bugs') ?></strong></a>
        </p>
        <address><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCopyright() ?></address>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not seeing my changes. Am I using the wrong path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving the changes follow these steps -

1. Remove your themes files from `pub/static`
2. Run this command

   `<youmagentodirecotry> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. Give folder permission 755 `pub/static`

Comment: I don't have SSH access at this time. Is there any way to run the static-content deploy code outside of the command line interface?

Comment: I didn't find any way yet.

Comment: I still don't have SSH access, but when I enabled developer mode via my htaccess file, I'm able to see changes to other template files like header.phtml, but I'm still not seeing this particular change that I was testing out in my original question.

Comment: check the magento documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: I turned on template path hints and realized that this particular template wasn't even being used! Thanks for your help! I guess my question is really invalid.

Comment: @Chandra so the problem is you don't set the theme?

Comment: @Chandra if you think like either accept any answer or delete the question..

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to override that template. Make sure you have flushed your full_page cache and are viewing the page you've modified with the chrome inspector window open or in incognito mode to disable browser cache.

Comment: I disabled the "Page Cache" and refreshed the page with no luck. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to test out the other answer.

Comment: These steps work for me too now that I'm editing templates that are being used (see accepted answer comments)

Answer (score 0):

For footer copyright, You need to check in

```
app/design/frontend/Mycompany/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/absolute_footer.phtml
```

or

```
app/design/frontend/Mycompany/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/copyright.phtml
```

Comment: Those 2 templates are under the <footer> code that cotains the footer links and newsletter block. I still haven't find the phtml that for the block over the absolute_footer.phtml  template.